# Transition Animation: all; Weird delay on margin-right

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have this simple app that when you click right, the right section comes in and when you click left, the left one comes in. It's like a carousel working with less code and the animation is purely CSS based.

Now when I click right, the animation is instant. On left, it takes a couple of seconds for it to begin.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{overflow:hidden}
.wrap{width:2500px;overflow:hidden}
.box{height:20px;width:20%;background:red;margin:20px 8px;float:left;

-webkit-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    var c = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    e.preventDefault;
    if (c == 39) {
      $(".box1").css("margin-left", "-100%");        
    }
    if (c == 37) {
      $(".box1").css("margin-left", "0");
    }
});
```

Is it something to do with the overflow? Is it a bug?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dp8VS/1/

Comment: It takes way too long for the left button to execute the animation (margin-left:0); http://jsfiddle.net/dp8VS/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.css("margin-left", "-100%")` sets the left-margin of `.box1` to `100%` of it's container (i.e. `2500px` in this case) so the transition isn't being delayed, it's just that it's taking a while for the div to move into view.

Since you're using a width of `20%` for your divs try:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.which === 39) {
        $(".box1").css("margin-left", "-20%");
    } else if (e.which === 37) {
        $(".box1").css("margin-left", "0");
    }

});
```

Also, jQuery 'normalises' a lot of the properties in the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) so I've just used `e.which` to get the key code.

The magic: http://jsfiddle.net/EThDb/3/

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how I missed that